# Django ORM, Q statements and customized sorting

Tags: django, django-models

I am simplifying this for clarity. Let's say I had this function that finds `Document` records based on a `requestedColor`.

```
def find_docs(requestedColor):
    docs = Document.objects.filter(Q(color=requestedColor) | Q(other_color=requestedColor))
```

I'd like to order the results so that Document found using `color` will appear before objects found with `other_color` and I want to do it within the query - without any external sorting.

Is there a way to do this within the ORM query? I could not find a way to do that.

Pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) to `annotate` a value which would indicate which field matched and order by this value:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When

docs = Document.objects.annotate(
    color_order=Case(
        When(color=requestedColor, then=Value(1, output_field=IntegerField())),
        When(other_color=requestedColor, then=Value(2, output_field=IntegerField())),
        default=Value(0, output_field=IntegerField()),
    )
).filter(
    Q(color=requestedColor) | Q(other_color=requestedColor)
).order_by('color_order')
```

Comment: shookran! just what I needed.